# Lombok SLF4J impl inheritance issues

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, lombok

I'm facing an issue with Lombok in my multimodule maven project. I have two classes :

```
@Slf4j
public class Parent {}

@Slf4j
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void m() {
        log.debug("hello");
    }
}
```

There is also a parent maven project in which the lombok dependency is defined. And a child maven project in which I define the parent project as maven parent.

When I use generated `log` instance in `Child` class, compilation error occurs :

```
[ERROR] log has private access in <Child class>
```

I could resolved the issue in two ways:

- I create myself the private field named "log" by hand.
- I define the Lombok dependency in the child maven project.

Why so? Any workaround / best way to define the lombok dependency ?

Thanks for your help.

Using :

- lombok 1.16.18
- JDK 1.8
- Maven 3.5.3

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance should not impact your issue in any way. When you use `@Slf4j` annotation Lombok creates `private static final` field and `static` fields are not inherited. In your case generated code looks like this:

```
public class Parent {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Parent.class);

    public Parent() {}
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Child.class);

    public Child() {}

    public void m() {
        log.debug("hello");
    }
}
```

With multi-module maven project you need to ensure that inter-module dependencies are specified correctly. If lombok is on the classpath everything should work perfectly fine out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I found why, the Lombok dependency in the dependencies tree of the child project was in provided scope. I added Lombok in dependency and the field was correctly generated then.

Comment: Lombok should always be added as `provided`, otherwise it will end up in your runtime classpath, and you do not want that.

Comment: Maven's `provided` has a Gradle equivalent `compileOnly` per docs at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html#migmvn:migrating_deps